# Coverting/ Casting operators to integer

Tags: t-sql, casting, type-conversion, operators

I want to convert/ cast these operators ( '/' and '*') if this is possible. Maybe you know how that works or you know what the internal coding of division and multiplication is?! Maybe then I can continue with that?

What I want to do is, based on the last number of the current system time, I want to decide if that number is odd or even, and then do a multiplication or division in the next calculations.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateFactor()
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @time DATETIME2(7) 
DECLARE @length INT
DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(20) 
DECLARE @operator NVARCHAR(20) 

SET @time = SYSDATETIME()
SELECT @length = LEN(@time)


SELECT @value = RIGHT(@time, 1);

IF (@value % 2 = 0) 
    SET @operator = '*'
ELSE SET @operator = '/'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(20) 
SET @SQL = '10' + @operator + '2'  --I get only 10 / 2 and 10 * 2 because that are strings and that is why I cannot get a result of the operation, but I want 5 and 20  

RETURN @SQL
END
GO
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is this a homework requirement? For a real life requirement this sounds rather weird... Or is it a case of the [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? Where is `10` and `2` coming from? If you want to get `5` or `20` back, you function should return `INT` and you will have either to execute the string as *dynamic SQL*, or you use the `IF` not to create a string, but to return either `10/2` or `10*2`...

Comment: `select DatePart( second, GetDate() ) % 2 as SecondsLSB;` handles the first part. A [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression should make quick work of the second part. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.